# wooCommerce custom end points

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am a fairly new PHP developer and  what I am trying to create is a custom endpoint for the "myaccount" page . I am trying to create a "Add Guest" end point. I am finding it very difficult to find any documentation online. What I have done so far is used this git hub repo

https://gist.github.com/neilgee/13ac00c86c903c4ab30544b2b76c483c/a43701564ab696e1586e2879591c890b67a5f1bf#file-woo-endpoints-order-php

I created these files and put them in the plugins/woocommerce/includes directory. But they seem to take no effect. Have i put them in the correct  directory? Am I soppose to call these classes somewhere else ? I have no idea where I going wrong. Can some please educate me on this matter.

```
<?php
/*
 * Add custom endpoint that appears in My Account Page - WooCommerce 2.6
 * Ref - https://gist.github.com/claudiosmweb/a79f4e3992ae96cb821d3b357834a005#file-custom-my-account-endpoint-php
 */


class My_Custom_My_Account_Endpoint {

    /**
     * Custom endpoint name.
     *
     * @var add_students_details
     */
    public static $endpoint = 'add_students_details';

    /**
     * Plugin actions.
     */
    public function __construct() {
        // Actions used to insert a new endpoint in the WordPress.
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'add_endpoints' ) );
        add_filter( 'query_vars', array( $this, 'add_query_vars' ), 0 );

        // Change the My Accout page title.
        add_filter( 'the_title', array( $this, 'endpoint_title' ) );

        // Insering your new tab/page into the My Account page.
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', array( $this, 'new_menu_items' ) );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_account_' . self::$endpoint .  '_endpoint', array( $this, 'endpoint_content' ) );
    }

    /**
     * Register new endpoint to use inside My Account page.
     *
     * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_endpoint/
     */

    public function add_endpoints() {
        add_rewrite_endpoint( self::$endpoint, EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );
    }

    /**
     * Add new query var.
     *
     * @param array $vars
     * @return array
     */
    public function add_query_vars( $vars ) {
        $vars[] = self::$endpoint;

        return $vars;
    }

    /**
     * Set endpoint title.
     *
     * @param string $title
     * @return string
     */
    public function endpoint_title( $title ) {
        global $wp_query;

        $is_endpoint = isset( $wp_query->query_vars[ self::$endpoint ] );

        if ( $is_endpoint && ! is_admin() && is_main_query() && in_the_loop() && is_account_page() ) {
            // New page title.
            $title = __( 'My Stuff', 'woocommerce' );

            remove_filter( 'the_title', array( $this, 'endpoint_title' ) );
        }

        return $title;
    }

    /**
     * Insert the new endpoint into the My Account menu.
     *
     * @param array $items
     * @return array
     */
    public function new_menu_items( $items ) {
        // Remove the logout menu item.
        $logout = $items['customer-logout'];
        unset( $items['customer-logout'] );
        // Insert your custom endpoint.
        $items[ self::$endpoint ] = __( 'My Stuff', 'woocommerce' );

        // Insert back the logout item.
        $items['customer-logout'] = $logout;

        return $items;
    }

    /**
     * Endpoint HTML content.
     */
    public function endpoint_content() {
        wc_get_template( 'myaccount/navigation.php' ); ?>

        <div class="woocommerce-MyAccount-content">

            <p>Hello World! - custom field can go here</p>

        </div>

        <?php
    }

    /**
     * Plugin install action.
     * Flush rewrite rules to make our custom endpoint available.
     */
    public static function install() {
        flush_rewrite_rules();
    }
}

new My_Custom_My_Account_Endpoint();

// Flush rewrite rules on plugin activation.
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( 'My_Custom_My_Account_Endpoint', 'install' ) );
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include all relevant code in your question.

Comment: @SteffenD.Sommer Hi there thanks for the reply. Is that okay did I add the code correctly.

Comment: Almost. The code snippet feature is intended for HTML/CSS/JS. Since your code is PHP, I would suggest using a code block instead.

Comment: Instead of adding this to the WooCommerce folder, you probably need to wrap it into it's own plugin.

Comment: Hey @helgatheviking thank you for the reply . I think that you are right . I am going to try to implement this now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But they seem to take no effect. Have i put them in the correct directory? Am I soppose to call these classes somewhere else ? I have no idea where I going wrong. Can some please educate me on this matter.

First thing, you created a class, but you never loaded that file or initiated the class. The best way to do this would be in your own plugin.

Second, you have to add the `add_rewrite_endpoint()` to the install function. Otherwise, it doesn't know to register the new endpoint and your rewrite rules are flushed, but end up exactly the same as they were before... which creates some 404 errors.

Third, recent WooCommerce provides a filter for the endpoint title. And the content doesn't need to reproduce the My Account div or navigation.

Tested and working:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: WC Custom Endpoint
 * Plugin URI:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38784599/woocommerce-custom-end-points
 * Description: A custom endpoint
 * Version:     0.1.0
 * Author:      Kathy Darling
 * Author URI:  http://kathyisawesome.com
 * Text Domain: wc_custom_endpoint
 * Domain Path: /languages
 * Requires at least: 4.6.0
 * Tested up to: 4.6.0  
 *
 * Copyright: © 2016 Kathy Darling.
 * License: GNU General Public License v3.0
 * License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html
 */


/**
 * The Main WC_Custom_Endpoint class
 **/
if ( ! class_exists( 'WC_Custom_Endpoint' ) ) :

class WC_Custom_Endpoint {

    const VERSION = '0.1.0';

    /**
     * Custom endpoint name.
     */
    public static $endpoint = 'add_students_details';

    /**
     * @var WC_Custom_Endpoint - the single instance of the class
     * @since 0.1.0
     */
    protected static $instance = null;            

    /**
     * Plugin Directory
     *
     * @since 0.1.0
     * @var string $dir
     */
    public $dir = '';

    /**
     * Plugin URL
     *
     * @since 0.1.0
     * @var string $url
     */
    public $url = '';


    /**
     * Main WC_Custom_Endpoint Instance
     *
     * Ensures only one instance of WC_Custom_Endpoint is loaded or can be loaded.
     *
     * @static
     * @see WC_Custom_Endpoint()
     * @return WC_Custom_Endpoint - Main instance
     * @since 0.1.0
     */
    public static function instance() {
        if ( ! isset( self::$instance ) && ! ( self::$instance instanceof WC_Custom_Endpoint ) ) {
            self::$instance = new WC_Custom_Endpoint();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }


    public function __construct(){

        $this->dir = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__);

        $this->url = plugin_dir_url(__FILE__);

        // Load translation files
        add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( $this, 'load_plugin_textdomain' ) );

        // Actions used to insert a new endpoint in the WordPress.
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'add_endpoints' ) );
        add_filter( 'query_vars', array( $this, 'add_query_vars' ), 0 );

        // Insering your new tab/page into the My Account page.
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', array( $this, 'new_menu_items' ) );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_endpoint_' . self::$endpoint .  '_title', array( $this, 'endpoint_title' ) );    
        add_action( 'woocommerce_account_' . self::$endpoint .  '_endpoint', array( $this, 'endpoint_content' ) );

    }


    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /* Localization */
    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/


    /**
     * Make the plugin translation ready
     *
     * @return void
     * @since  1.0
     */
    public function load_plugin_textdomain() {
        load_plugin_textdomain( 'wc-custom-endpoint' , false , dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) .  '/languages/' );
    }

    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /* Endpoint */
    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    /**
     * Register new endpoint to use inside My Account page.
     *
     * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_endpoint/
     */

    public function add_endpoints() {
        add_rewrite_endpoint( self::$endpoint, EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );
    }

    /**
     * Add new query var.
     *
     * @param array $vars
     * @return array
     */
    public function add_query_vars( $vars ) {
        $vars[] = self::$endpoint;

        return $vars;
    }


    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /* Display */
    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/


    /**
     * Set endpoint title.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function endpoint_title() {

        return __( 'My Stuff', 'wc_custom_endpoint' );

    }

    /**
     * Insert the new endpoint into the My Account menu.
     *
     * @param array $items
     * @return array
     */
    public function new_menu_items( $items ) {
        // Remove the logout menu item.
        $logout = $items['customer-logout'];
        unset( $items['customer-logout'] );
        // Insert your custom endpoint.
        $items[ self::$endpoint ] = __( 'My Stuff', 'wc_custom_endpoint' );

        // Insert back the logout item.
        $items['customer-logout'] = $logout;

        return $items;
    }

    /**
     * Endpoint HTML content.
     */
    public function endpoint_content() { ?>
        <p>Hello World! - custom wc_get_template() can go here</p>

        <?php
    }

    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /* Activation */
    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    /**
     * Plugin install action.
     * Flush rewrite rules to make our custom endpoint available.
     */
    public static function install() {
        WC_Custom_Endpoint()->add_endpoints();
        flush_rewrite_rules();
    }

    /**
     * Plugin install action.
     * Flush rewrite rules to make our custom endpoint available.
     */
    public static function uninstall() {
        flush_rewrite_rules();
    }

} //end class: do not remove or there will be no more guacamole for you

endif; // end class_exists check


/**
 * Returns the main instance of WC_Custom_Endpoint to prevent the need to use globals.
 *
 * @since  1.0
 * @return WC_Custom_Endpoint
 */
function WC_Custom_Endpoint() {
    return WC_Custom_Endpoint::instance();
}

// Launch the whole plugin
add_action( 'woocommerce_loaded', 'WC_Custom_Endpoint' );

// register activation hook
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( 'WC_Custom_Endpoint', 'install' ) );
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, array( 'WC_Custom_Endpoint', 'uninstall' ) );
```

Comment: Thanks very much this is excellent . Thank you for educating me on this. :D

Comment: Sure, you were about 80% of the way there.