# wc_get_template returning null

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I can't seem to get the `wc_get_template()` to return my page template. I am sure the path is correct to where I have it stored in my child theme folder but when I run it I get `NULL`. Can you see anything wrong here?

```
public function endpoint_content() { 

    // The template name. 
    $template_name = 'Students Details'; 

    // (default: array()) 
    $args = array(); 

    // The template path. 
    $template_path =  get_stylesheet_directory().'/woocommerce/myaccount/add_students.php';

    // NOTICE! Understand what this does before running. 
    $res = wc_get_template($template_name, $args, $template_path, $template_path);

    var_dump($res); 
}
```

Comment: Looking at the code for the [`wc_get_template()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_get_template.html#177-206) function, it isn't expected to return anything. It specifies 'returns: void' in other docs.

Comment: Maybe look at [`wc_get_template_html()`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-core-functions.php) which is '_...like wc_get_template but returns the html instead of outputting it_'.

Comment: @Henders hey thanks for the reply . So I have tried wc_get_template_html()  and its returned string(0) "" so I am wondering is it maybe because It is a child theme. If I use a include statement it works fine. But i do not know if its good practice  .

Comment: Not sure to be quite honest. It's likely to be the arguments you are passing through are invalid in some way. I just had a quick glance at the code to see what it should be returning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are passing the wrong arguments to `wc_get_template()`.

1. `$template_name` is the full name so `myaccount/student-details.php`
2. `$template_path` is an empty string. Usually, WC will look in the theme's `woocommerce` folder
3. `$default_path` this is the path to your plugin's templates. In this case add a `templates` folder into the root folder of the plugin I created for you in your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38784599/woocommerce-custom-end-points)

Here's the updated function:

```
/**
 * Endpoint HTML content.
 */
public function endpoint_content() {    

    // The template name. 
    $template_name = 'myaccount/student-details.php'; 

    // default args
    $args = array(); 

    // default template
    $template_path = ''; // use default which is usually "woocommerce"

    // default path (look in plugin file!)
    $default_path = untrailingslashit( plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) ) . '/templates/';

    // call the template
    wc_get_template($template_name, $args, $template_path, $default_path);

}
```

And here's a sample template `wc-your-custom-endpoint-plugin/templates/student-details.php`:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template
 * 
 * @author      Kathy Darling
 * @package     WC_Custom_Endpoint/Templates
 * @version     0.1.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly
?>

<?php do_action( 'wc_custom_endpoint_before_student_details' ); ?>

<p><?php _e( 'Hello World!', 'wc-custom-endpoint' ); ?><p>

<?php do_action( 'wc_custom_endpoint_after_student_details' ); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you again helgatheviking you saved me again . :D